# Executable file whose shortcut is in start-up folder doesn't launch on startup

Tags: windows-10

Following [this explanation](https://www.wikihow.com/Start-XAMPP-at-Startup-in-Windows) I'm trying to make "Xampp" launch during Windows startup, however the executable file simply doesn't launch during Windows startup.

When I double-click on the shortcut, it does launch and I get a "Do you want to allow this app from an unknown published to make changes to your devices?" modal. If I click everything works.

Any idea why it doesn't launch at startup?

EDIT: in Xampp control panel, I checked the "service" options for Apache and MySQL. Now, when I launch Xampp, these two automatically start. But that's not exactly what I want: I want Xampp itself to launch automatically when Windows start. I notice that every single time I launch Xampp, I get a Windows prompt asking me to confirm the launch of this application from an unknown publisher. Perhaps that's the problem? If so, how can I solve it?

Comment: Google ["Xampp as a service"](https://www.google.com/search?q=xampp+as+a+service&rlz=1C1CHBD_enUS868US868&oq=Xampp+as+a+service).

Comment: Go to the following path:C:\ ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\ Start Menu\Programs. Copy the shortcut into the XAMPP folder and paste it into the Startup folder. For your reference:https://technowikis.com/34691/how-to-start-xampp-in-windows-10-automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Launch the XAMPP control panel.
2. Stop all the running XAMPP components by clicking the "Stop" button next to each component.
3. Click the "Service" button next to each component to install it as a service. Click "Yes" when prompted to confirm. This will install the corresponding service and set it to start automatically on boot.
4. Reboot your system and the selected components should start automatically.

Information obtained from [this site](http://www.sintesisdigital.com.mx/dashboard/docs/auto-start-xampp.html).

Comment: Thank you! However I realized after rebooting my machine that it still doesn't solve my issue, please check my edit in the question.

Comment: Have you looked in the service control manager (for windows) to see if the services are there? run `services.msc`.

Comment: Thanks, yes I see Apache and MySQL there. But Xampp still doesn't launch on Windows startup...

Comment: So what does XAMPP give you if those services are already running?  I don't understand.

Comment: Sorry you're right it does work, I thought it didn't because I couldn't see the Xampp console running but even without that I can access localhost. Thank you :)